# GraphQL issue / interface

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

## Question

What am I doing wrong? GitHub has something similar and it works.

## #EDIT

With ***graphql-tools*** everything works. But how can I make it works without additional dependencies?

### Query

```
query Help {
  node(id: 1) {
    id
    ... on Client {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```

## Response from server

Generated Schema cannot use Interface or Union types for execution.

### Schema + resolver

```
const schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    node(id: Int): Node
  }

  interface Node {
    id: Int!
  }

  type Client implements Node {
    id: Int!
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
  }
`)

const root = {
  node: () => {
    // Experiment
    return {
      id: 1,
      firstName: 'A',
      lastName: 'B'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I messed up, looks like this could be an issue with apollo https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1741